# Android MyLocationOverlay - marker disappear after a period of time

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, mylocationoverlay

I want to show the user's location on a map view. Therefore I use '`MyLocationOverlay`. The marker appears on the map view and will be updated/moved when the location of the user changes. 
But if the `onLocationChanged` method will not be triggered for a while then the marker disappers. But I want that the marker will always be shown although the location of the user not changes.

Here's the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);    
    MyLocationOverlay locationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this,mapView);
    locationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    mapView.getOverlays().add(locationOverlay);

    locationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mapController.animateTo(locationOverlay.getMyLocation());
        }
    });

    //request for location changes
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    mapView.postInvalidate();
}
```

Anyone had the same problem or knows how to fix it?